# How to differentiate between two `chrome://*/` tabs via chrome api?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to differentiate using API like this

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, (tabs) => { console.log(tabs); })
```

props of a normal website `tab` looks like this:

```
active: true
audible: false
autoDiscardable: true
discarded: false
favIconUrl: "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196"
groupId: -1
height: 694
highlighted: true
id: 746548355
incognito: false
index: 22
lastAccessed: 1710739015962.401
mutedInfo: {muted: false}
openerTabId: 746548309
pinned: false
selected: true
status: "complete"
title: "How to"
url: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
width: 1280
windowId: 746548058
```

I am observing `tab` for internal pages ie

```
 chrome://password-manager/*
 chrome://downloads/
 chrome://history/
 chrome://settings/
 chrome://extensions/
```

all return the same, they neither return a `url` attribute or `favIconUrl` attribute or `title` attribute.
they all looks like this:

```
active: false
audible: false
autoDiscardable: true
discarded: false
groupId: -1
height: 694
highlighted: false
id: 746548360
incognito: false
index: 25
lastAccessed: 1710739500261.044
mutedInfo: {muted: false}
openerTabId: 746548355
pinned: false
selected: false
status: "complete"
width: 1280
windowId: 746548058
```

Comment: You need to add "tabs" to "permissions" in manifest.json.